# Do parts of a minor fast start before morning?

Tags: halacha, fast-days

I've always understood that minor fasts run from morning (a bit before dawn) until nightfall.  An [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92491/472) to [What activities (other than eating and drinking) are forbidden on minor fasts?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51244/what-activities-other-than-eating-and-drinking-are-forbidden-on-minor-fasts), however, cites the Mishnah Berurah as saying:

> [A] pious person should be stringent on all of them as on Tish'ah Be'Av, but if one of them falls on the evening when [a man's wife is due to] immerse, he should fulfill his obligation.

I wondered how this could even be an issue -- a woman immerses at night, so by the time she's home from the *mikvah* the fast would surely be over.  Joel K there speculated that the MB might be talking about the night *before* (e.g. the night between 9 Tevet and 10 Tevet).  I also note that the MB is talking about a *pious* person, not necessarily *halacha*.

This all leaves me confused about pre-fast activities.  According to *halacha*, which if any fast-day changes begin before the start of the fast in the morning?

Comment: Sefardim say aneinu even at maariv

Comment: Also, this isn't strictly related to the fast day, but at a plag mincha/maariv that I once went to on erev Shiv'a Asar Betamuz, the gabbai announced before maariv "If you daven maariv, you're accepting the three weeks.  If you'd like to listen to music or get a haircut in the next hour, please leave now."  (And he made a similar announcement about eating meat 2 weeks later on erev Rosh Chodesh Av.)

Comment: @Heshy Are you sure they say Aneinu at Maariv? See [here](http://sephardic.org/halachot/chapter_detail/14/laws-of-the-prayer) where it says only Shacharit and Minchah.

Comment: @JoelK I've never seen it personally, but https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69667

Comment: @Heshy Interesting. Thanks. Following the link in that answer to Peninei Halacha, it seems that Teimanim and some Sephardim will say it at Ma’ariv, but most Sephardim will only say it at Shacharit and Mincha. This is probably enough for an answer, no?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35430431#35430431

Comment: [related](/q/13011)

Answer (score 4):

1. As alluded to by Double AA in a [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92494/do-parts-of-a-minor-fast-start-before-morning#comment301098_92494) on the question, the fast really begins when one retires for the night. Thus, when one wakes up, even if this before dawn, he may no longer eat (unless he stipulated otherwise before going to sleep). See [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayyim 564](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.564.1?lang=bi).
2. As noted by Heshy in a [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92494/do-parts-of-a-minor-fast-start-before-morning#comment301083_92494) on the question, Teimanim and some Sepharadim say Aneinu at *ma'ariv* on the night preceding a fast day. See Peninei Halachah [here](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/05-07-10/).

Answer (score 3):

I had to read MB commentary in O.C. 550:2 a few times. In it he says that a pious person should enact the 5 restrictions which includes marital relations **just like it's done on Tish'a B'Av** - meaning, that it starts at the night time (*tzet* of the beginning of say 10 Tevet.) So, he would fast as well as keep the other 4 restrictions from nightfall - all as if it were Tish'a B'Av.

Thus, when it says that a woman should immerse at night and the husband should have marital relations with his wife if this her *mikvah* night, it means the night of the beginning of say, 10 Tevet. It seems that this situation is the exception for the pious people, but they would still be fasting and enacting the other 4 restrictions at night.

Comment: +1 Note that in the sha’ar hatziyun there (550:9) he says explicitly (quoting Eliyahu Rabbah in the name of the Shlah) that a ba’al nefesh should fast at night.