# What happens if an individual accidentally says Aneinu before Re'eh instead of during Shema Koleinu?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shemoneh-esrei, fast-days

Let’s say that a congregant, who’s normally [supposed to say Aneinu in Shema Koleinu instead of before Re'eh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69658/), accidentally says it as a stand-alone Beracha before Re'eh. He doesn’t realize until well after 3-4 seconds.

1. Does he have to say Aneinu again during Shema Koleinu?
2. Does it count as a Beracha said in vain?

Answer (score 7):

The Kaf HaChaim writes [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.565.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that you fulfilled your obligation if you accidentally says it as a stand-alone Beracha before Re'eh. Therefore:

1 - You do not say it again in Shema Koleinu.

2 - It was not a Beracha in vain.